# Why does binary reader put all the content of my 2d array into a single array row?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, binaryreader, binarywriter

I am trying to use binary writer/reader to serialize and deserialize a 2D array, this is the code I am using for this:

```
public class Connect4BoardData : ASerializable
{
    public int[,] board = new int[6, 7] { 
                                                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} };
    public int rows = 6, columns = 7;
    public override void Serialize(Packet pPacket)
            {
       
                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                    {
                        pPacket.Write(board[i, j]);
                    }
                }
            }
            public override void Deserialize(Packet pPacket)
            {
                rows = 6;
                columns = 7;
                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                    {
                        board[i, j] = pPacket.ReadInt();
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

When I eventually try to read it however, it just doesn't work. I seem to get a [42, 1] array instead, and I honestly do not understand why it happens. If I try `array.GetLength(1)`, I get an "index out of bounds exception for some reason, but I am still able to access `array[x, 0]`, where x is 0 to 41. Moreover when I attempted to write and read columns and rows in the methods, it read them as

```
 rows = 6, columns = 70000000000000 ...
```

The code to write and read ints is as follows:

```
public void Write (int pInt)                            {       writer.Write(pInt);    }
public int ReadInt()                                    { return reader.ReadInt32();   }
```

with writer and reader assigned like this:

```
    private BinaryWriter writer;    //only used in write mode, to write bytes into a byte array
    private BinaryReader reader;    //only used in read mode, to read bytes from a byte array

    /**
     * Create a Packet for writing.
     */
    public Packet()
    {
        //BinaryWriter wraps a Stream, in this case a MemoryStream, which in turn wraps an array of bytes
        writer = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream());
    }

    /**
     * Create a Packet from an existing byte array so we can read from it
     */
    public Packet (byte[] pSource)
    {
        //BinaryReader wraps a Stream, in this case a MemoryStream, which in turn wraps an array of bytes
        reader = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(pSource));
    }
```

EDIT: Serialize and Deserialize is called like this:

```
public void Write (ASerializable pSerializable)         {
            //write the full classname into the stream first
            Write(pSerializable.GetType().FullName);
            //then ask the serializable object to serialize itself
            pSerializable.Serialize(this); 
        }
public ASerializable ReadObject() 
        {
            //get the classname from the stream first
            Type type = Type.GetType(ReadString());
            //create an instance of it through reflection (requires default constructor)
            ASerializable obj = (ASerializable)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            obj.Deserialize(this);
            return obj;
        }
```

Everything else I write and read works fine, 1D arrays, strings, booleans. I hope I provided enough info and context, but if not let me know and I'll update the question ASAP, its quite a large assignment.
And one more thing, I am not going to be using BinaryFormatter for this, its an assignment that requires BianryWriter/Reader, so please don't recommend this in answers

Thank you!

Comment: "When I eventually try to read it however, it just doesn't work. " To be clear: you do this by calling `Deserialize`? When you try this, does `board` have the correct shape before the call? Instead of trying to show each relevant part of the code in isolation, it would be better to try to create a self-contained [mre] - a program that does all of the steps you are talking about, does nothing else, and demonstrates the erroneous behaviour. Please also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel
I will update the question with details of how it is called.

Comment: `Moreover when I attempted to write and read columns and rows in the methods, it read them as rows = 6, columns = 70000000000000 ` well nothing you've shown us changes columns, so either you're printing it wrong or you're not showing us the relevant part of your code. I don't see ANY debug statements so I'm assuming it's both. Between this and the `The code to [...] read ints is as follows: public int ReadInt()` business, you haven't given us much to go on. I know it returns an int, I want to see HOW it does that and how it advances in the byte array. +1 to needing a minimal example.